# Running php in cmd gives access is denied and "This app can't run on your PC"

Tags: php, cmd, environment-variables, composer-php, access-denied

I have installed xampp on my windows 8.1 and wanted to add PHP to environmental variables. Therefore, under path i added ;C:\xampp\php; in the end, like i have done some long time ago.

Now, when i try to run any php function in `cmd`, i get the windows message

```
"This app can't run on your PC.."
```

and a `"Access is denied"` in `cmd`.

If i remove php from the path variable, i still get the same error.

What i suspect could be a problem is that when trying to add the variable by typing `SET PATH=%PATH%` I accidentally clicked `enter` and therefore might have added an some weird value, although i have double checked and the whole line looks fine (no weird leftovers or something).

Comment: Does the user which is running the PHP Script have access to execute?

Comment: @DarylGill Yes it is the administrator user and i was able to do this with everything else. Although, now that i tried to run cmd as administrator, i am allowed to run PHP.
This would pop up another question: how can i fix access to allow this in normal mode?

Comment: right click on the php folder -> properties -> security tab and give at least read and execution access for your user.

Comment: Well, first of all, my account is an administrator account. Second of all, when looking into permissions of the php folder, every user is allowed to read & execute, whereas the administrator has absolutely full control..
See below:
[link](http://s29.postimg.org/80f8x6mbr/Capture.png)

Comment: does `php --version` work in the user account? The "This app can't run on your PC.." usually pops up when you try to run a 64bit app within a 32bit operating system or if the file is corrupted. To make sure that your path variable is not the problem try to run with the full php path like `C:\xampp\php\php.exe --version`. Did you try giving full control to the user account for the php folder?

Comment: I have added the PATH environmental variable to the user specific variables and now it seems to be working. Thank you all for help :)

Comment: I just removed PATH variable and added it back - problem solved !

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem, I have tried a lot of things, but without success ... At the end of my efforts, I noticed that the size php.exe is 0KB , so I copy php.exe from my backup folder, where size is php.exe 75kB and php via cmd works

Comment: Strange, but this just happened to me. Something I did from the command line caused the php.exe file to be modified, and mine was also 0kb (and not 120kb).

Comment: lol same thing happened to me as well...thanks for pointing it out

Comment: This solution works, just make sure you confirm that your php.ini file is 0kb before overwriting. Always back up before any change around this area.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem, when I'm using composer(Dependency Manager for PHP). Then I realised the problem was coming from php.exe.

The causes of the error message "Access denied" in php.exe and possible solutions:

- Path variable may be not added, so make sure that your path variable is added properly.
- The antivirus software may have blocked access to the php.exe file. Check your antivirus software's log and quarantine.
- You don't have the permissions to run the php.exe. Change the permissions of the file.
- The php.exe file may have been damaged. Reinstall the application.
- Some malware can be added a php.exe file into windows or system32 directory. Since default path variable includes those directories, operating system will load that malware rather than original php.exe . So try by adding your PHP directory path to the top of the path variable.(this was the problem in my case)

Refer this [link](http://exescan.net/exes/p/php-exe-file) for more details on common php.exe errors.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
(My PHP installation lives in `C:\PHP`. Administrator has sufficient rights.)

1. Added `C:\PHP` to PATH variable
2. **Removed the 0Kb php.exe file that lived in C:\Windows\System32**
   (I guess this file caused the windows refusal to execute)